# Powershell Switchcase for CSV Filtering-> Process runtrough ->and Ouput

Tags: powershell, csv, filter, switch-statement

I would like to be able to select which csv runs through as the input csv's are standardiesd and i need to filter for the process. My problem is i cant handle the Filter part. The Process is running fine i tested it several times. Also the csv load is working and the save at part as well those got tested seperatly as well. But as soon as the switchcase and the filter part are in it doesnt work anymore. But i need it as otherwise i have to write 3 more scripts what wouldnt make sense. Any recommandtion how to pass this filter.

**Full Code**

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

#Select which option and which CSV

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$form.Text = "CSV Liste"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,300) 
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,195)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,195)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20) 
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$label.Text = "Welche CSV Liste soll geladen werden:"
$form.Controls.Add($label) 

$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox 
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40) 
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$listBox.Height = 150

[void] $listBox.Items.Add("AS400 Computer")
[void] $listBox.Items.Add("AS400 Personalstamm")
[void] $listBox.Items.Add("ADComputer")
[void] $listBox.Items.Add("ADBenutzer")



$form.Controls.Add($listBox) 

$form.Topmost = $True

$result = $form.ShowDialog()

#Filter for the CSV

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $location = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $location.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $location.filter = "CSV (*.csv)| *.csv"
    $location.ShowDialog()

    $CSV = Import-Csv -Path $location.FileName -UseCulture


    $x = $listBox.SelectedItem

    switch ($x)
    {
        "AS400 Computer"
        {
            $y = $CSV | Select Inventarnummer
        }

        "AS400 Personalstamm" 
        {
            $y = $CSV | Select filter1
        }

        "ADComputer" 
        {
            $y = $CSV | Select filter1
        }

        "ADBenutzer" 
        {
            $y = $CSV | Select filter1
        }  
    }
}

#Save Data at

$Saveworking = New-Object -Typename System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
$Saveworking.filter = "CSV (*.csv)| *.csv"
$Saveworking.ShowDialog()

$Savefailed = New-Object -Typename System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
$Savefailed.filter = "CSV (*.csv)| *.csv"
$Savefailed.ShowDialog()

#Process Runtrough

foreach($n in $y)
{
    try {
        $Computer = [system.net.dns]::resolve($n.NAME) | Select HostName,AddressList 
        $IP = ($Computer.AddressList).IPAddressToString
        Write-Host $n.NAME $IP
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{IPAddress=$IP; Name=$n.NAME} | Export-Csv $Saveworking.FileName -NoTypeInformation -Append
    } catch {
        Write-Host "$($n.NAME) is unreachable."
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name=$n.NAME} | Export-Csv $Savefailed.FileName -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }
}
```

edit: Code updated can now select Column and is working allmost. As it seems it cant run the Process right now as it is not felxible enough. Working on Solution appricate any recommandtions.

Comment: Whats not happening?

Comment: The filter part is not working properly. As i cant filter out the right column of the csv